# Правильный алгоритм переноса Excel таблицы в Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, excel

Есть таблица excel с n-количеством листов, m-количеством строк, z - количеством столбцов.

Необходимо перенести её в Java Swing JTable.

Не работал со свингом, но накидал примерный алгоритм. Поправьте, что не так:

```
int list = парсим кол-во листов;
int a=0;
int b=0;
int stolb=0;
int strok=0;
for(int i=0;i<list;i++){
stolb = количество ненулевых стобцов текущего листа;
strok =  количество ненулевых строк;
создай новую таблицу размером (stolb;strok);
для ячеек JTable(a;b) = парсируй ячейки из excel(a;b);
}
```

правильно ли я составил алгоритм?

кто может преобразовать алгоритм в работающий метод?

для парсирования Excel используется библиотека POI Apache.

судя по комментариям начал пытаться реализовать пришел вот к этому :

у меня есть массив с названиями столбцов

```
Holod.Header
```

с помощью цикла для двухмерных массивов можно вот так вот парсить данные из нужной мне таблицы Excel

```
Holod.sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j)
```

типом данных является

```
HSSFCell
```

собственно сам код:

```
package kursach;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import tovars.Holod;

public class start extends JFrame {

 public static void createGUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test frame");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      String [] columnNames = new String[Holod.Header.size()];
      for (int i = 0; i < Holod.Header.size(); i++) {
        columnNames[i]=Holod.Header.get(i).toString();
      }

      String [][] data = new String [Holod.countStrok][Holod.countStolbc];
      for (int j = 1; j < Holod.countStolbc; j++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < Holod.countStrok; i++) {
          data[j][i]= Holod.sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).toString();
         }
       }

      JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

       JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

       frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
       frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 200));
       frame.pack();
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       frame.setVisible(true);
  }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                createGUI();
           }
      });
  }
  }
```

смысл в чем :

я замучился.
у меня не получается как следует создать таблицу, то

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

и прочее-прочее.
Посмотрите что не так. Целый час сижу не получается сделать два массива. Проклятье.

спустя час :

```
    int noOfColumns = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
    int noOfRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

    HSSFCell[] columnNames = new HSSFCell[noOfColumns];
    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
        columnNames[i] = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(i);
    }

    HSSFCell[][] data = new HSSFCell[noOfColumns][noOfRows];
    for (int j = 1; j < noOfColumns + 1; j++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < noOfRows + 1; i++) {
            data[j][i] = sheet.getRow(j).getCell(i);
            System.out.println(data[j][i]);
        }
    }
```

вылетает:

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
```

Comment: Во-первых индексы массива начинаются с 0, а во-вторых исключение вылетает потому что выходите за пределы массива. Делайте так: for (int j = 0; j < noOfColumns; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++) {
            data[j][i] = sheet.getRow(j).getCell(i);
            System.out.println(data[j][i]);
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У JTable есть метод setModel(TableModel dataModel).

Comment: допустим, что за входные параметры?

Comment: TableModel - это интерфейс. Его реализует, например, DefaultTableModel. Посмотрите пример: http://mymemoryjob.blogspot.ru/2011/08/swing-jtable-defaulttablemodel.html

Comment: Почитал. Интересная информация, но вот только со строками не понятно. Так что чуть-чуть не по теме, тут ведь парсируемые данные, заранее они неизвестны)

Comment: По сути будет кнопка в GUI отвечающая за перелистывание листов,а также чтобы эти таблицы полностью копировали таблицы из excel. Используя POI apache

Comment: 1. Из нужного листа читаете данные (парсите)
2. Создаете DefaultTableModel по какому-то событию и передаете JTable

DefaultTableModel можно создавать, например, через двумерный массив данных:
http://javatalks.ru/topics/41805

Comment: С массивом можно поподробнее? Можете считать меня новичком, но мне важно знать как быть с массивом.
Т.е. мне нужно создать массив [][], а далее? как в него заносить данные,чтобы при n столбцов было m строк?

Comment: String[][] str = new String[m][n];
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
 for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  str[i][j] = "Значение";
 }
}

Comment: спасибо,попробую отпишу)

Comment: я замучался, отредактирую сейчас вопрос покажу где остановился